# Rotation animation in horizontal scrollview on images Obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, scrollview

I have a question, I want to have just a little rotation animation on my images in a horizontal scrollview. They should rotate when they slide in, and when they slide out. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I want them to rotate when I scroll.

Ive tried something but it doesn't rotate when I scroll (only the first image)
I did something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
    UIImageView *view = [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex: page];

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x > lastX)
    {
        NSLog(@"scroll right");
        [view setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / scrollView.contentOffset.x + 0.1)];

    }
    else if(scrollView.contentOffset.x < lastX)
    {
        NSLog(@"scroll left");
        [view setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / scrollView.contentOffset.x - 0.1)];
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

Comment: But you could use the x coordinate of the contentOffset of the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CGAffineTransformRotate.
But before you have to set anchor point of the imageView. By Default it is set to (0.5, 0.5) i.e. the image will rotate from center.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    imageView.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreeInRadians); // -- 2 --
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // left blank
}];
```

Comment: in the animation block rotate to some degree, like imageView.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-pi/3); and then in completion block rotate it back to normal, like [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    imageView.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
} completion:nil];

Comment: I want the images to rotate when i scroll. not just once.